# JavaScript - Change key of multidimensional array from string to int

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

Using JavaScript, how would one convert array with structure like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    ["Item"] => "Vehicle"
                    ["Value"] => "BMW"
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    ["Item"] => "Vehicle"
                    ["Value"] => "Audi"
                )

        )
```

To instead of using string keys, use int keys, like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => "Vehicle"
                    [1] => "BMW"
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => "Vehicle"
                    [1] => "Audi"
                )

        )
```

Let me know if my question is clear and thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array with the keys for the right order and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for returning an array with the values.

```js
var array = [{ Item: "Vehicle", Value: "BMW" }, { Item: "Vehicle", Value: "Audi" }],
    keys = ['Item', 'Value'],
    newArray = array.map(function (a) {
        return keys.map(function (k) {
            return a[k];
        });
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newArray, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Additionally, you could use the `Object.keys` method to extract an array of keys from an object. Although for most use cases it's probably safer to manually define them... (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)